# Iterate through an EnumSet in java?

Tags: java, enums, loops

When I create an EnumSet and send it via a function, I find myself unable to reach the Enum values set inside the EnumSet. All I can do is compare it to the original set and check if it is present. I do not want that since that forces me to waste lines of code and forces me to reach out for the Original Enum class every single time.

```
    for(Action a : Action.values())
    {
        if(stateCommands.contains(a))
        {
            System.out.println(a.getCommand() + a.getDescription());
        }

    }
```

I want to iterate through stateCommands and be able to see its content.

How should I proceed with this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for(StateCommand command : stateCommands) {
   // do whatever
}
```

Just like any other `Set`.  Or, if you need to do something more sophisticated, just use the `stateCommands.iterator()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you leave the EnumSet generic, the following will **NOT** work:

```
public void StateLoop(EnumSet stateCommands){
    //won't work b/c stateCommands is treated as a generic Object
    for(StateCommand command : stateCommands) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```

However, if a Type is provided for the EnumSet it will work fine:

```
public void StateLoop(EnumSet<StateCommand> stateCommands){
    for(StateCommand command : stateCommands) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```